# Run! A giant chipmunk is attacking the city--or is it?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, military-defense

A chipmunk. 300x normal size. Dangerous. Especially when attacking a city. But there are some unknowns.
I have some obstacles to get around.
1: A chipmunk can hold a pound of food in each cheek pouch. Does this mean it could hold three 100 pound humans in each pouch?
2: Would this creature move on all fours or upright? It is very strong and can withstand the weight and can move its huge legs, but
3: Can it move fast? And would it be able to not trip over buildings?
4: If this monster is possible to create, could the city defend themselves? The city is equivalent to a modern-day city.
5: I want the chipmunk to be able to throw huge nuts, but is this even possible? Remember he is very strong.
How could I get around these obstacles?
Clarification Edit:
It will throw nuts at vehicles like planes and tanks. However, it have relatively poor eyesight. The world is partially magical, so it wouldn't collapse under it's weight. It's also how it got big. Assume it won't keel over and its muscle can move its legs.

Comment: You cannot put in magic into a question with a reality-check tag. Which do you want? Reality or not?

Comment: @SRM I agree. I answered by saying no, this isn't realistic, and adding magic invalidates the answer.

Comment: Hi there - I see more than 5 questions in this "question." Typically, we like to have around *one* question per post. This question is too broad and opinion based once you invalidate the "it's not possible" answer (It's the only correct answer), and I'm voting to close as such.

Comment: What @Aify said. Besides the unrealism of this (which you could, in principle, lampshade away using an appropriate amount of handwavium), you are simply asking too much at once. You might start with defining exactly what you mean by "300x size" (height? mass? or what?) and then focus on *one* aspect (for example, how fast it would be able to move, or how a human city could defend itself against a creature that size using those tactics). Once you have received satisfactory answers to that, take those answers as input to a *new* question that asks about some other aspect.

Comment: Compare also [Can you simply scale up animals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/316/29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **[The Square-Cube Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law#Biomechanics)** has arrived.

Your chipmunk's strength has increased by a factor of 300$^2$, or 90,000, but it's mass (weight) has increased by a factor of 300$^3$, or 27 million! That means it has to do 300$^1$, or 300, times as much work just to move. **That's just not possible**, regardless of how the chipmunk came to be - and that's why nothing on Earth can get that big.

- Its bones would snap under the weight
- Its muscles could not move that much weight anyways
- Its heart would not be able to pump blood throughout the entire body
- It couldn't really pump anything actually
- Its nerve impulses would be severely, cripplingly, delayed
- It would take a significantly larger amount of food - likely 300$^3$ (27 million) times as much
- Its nervous system, scaled up, could not possibly fight all the normal-sized pathogens attacking it (which would have much more space to enter through)
- Its brain could not possibly process the light entering its eyes or the frequency of sound entering its ears. Its tongue could not taste anything, nor could its nose smell.

**In short, physics stay normal-sized when you make something bigger.**
Just getting that out of the way because you used the [reality-check](/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag.

---

1. Both. It could fit that much mass (three people) in that volume (per cheek) but they would likely put up a fight.
2. It couldn't live, let alone walk. If you're ignoring all the reasons why it would die, you might as well have it walk as normal, or to be safe, take very small steps.
3. It would, realistically, die, but if you're pretending it wouldn't, it would be 300 times slower. The readers won't like that, so pretend it can go at normal speed.
4. The city would have to lure it somewhere (using a helicopter, maybe) to avoid civilian deaths, then blow up a bomb close to its heart or head to kill it. Assuming, of course, it wouldn't be crushed by its own weight, etc.
5. If the nuts are also scaled up, they will have 300$^3$ times the mass. Rounding their masses to 2 grams each at normal size, they will be about 119,059 pounds scaled up, or about 60 tons. That's enough to do damage.

Comment: The chipmunk is EXTREMELY strong, and it's body can withstand the weight.

Comment: For 4, it would just knock the copter out of the sky with a peanut. No dodging the shelled shells of doom.

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz That's not how it works. Physics stay normal-sized when you make an animal bigger, and that causes a hundred problems that will prevent it from being able to breathe, pump blood, move, see, basically everything. Of course it will be stronger, but it will be *heavier*, and its bones will *still* be made out of bone.

Comment: This world is partially magical. See edits again.

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz I would not recommend editing the question. Edits aren't supposed to invalidate answers, they're supposed to clarify what you mean.

Comment: It IS doing that, in a way.

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz As for throwing nuts, nonsense. You've just made the distance from its eyes and ears to its brain - and from its brain to its arm - three hundred times longer. It will take three hundred times as long to respond.

Comment: True. It's a weakness. But the nut is 300 times as big, so there is less chance of it missing.

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz Then the target will have three hundred times to move out of the way, more than enough time to strike.

Comment: The chipmunk can throw FAST!

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz If you invent a magical solution to every problem that arises then I don't know how to help you.

Comment: I said it was super strong.

Comment: @Bubbles_as_Jazz Again, I want to be able to help you but you can't add a magical solution - including that - when help is given. For all purposes just magic the rest of the creature.

Comment: The chipmunk has an origin story: It was used in a test by scientist. The lab blew up. It gave it strength and hugeness. But I guess you're right, I could say everything was taken care of by the explosion...