# What is the upper size limit on aquatic creatures?

Tags: biology, earth-like

I'm developing a planet populated by giant sea creatures (think Megalodon, but bigger.) While I know that gravity has an effect on size, the sources I found only made reference to land creatures, who can't grow past a certain size, or else their legs/bones would snap. Legs are obviously not a problem for sea creatures.

What things determine the upper size limit on aquatic creatures? How much effect does gravity have on aquatic size? Or is size more a function of available food (which is what I've heard about blue whales)?

(First-time asker, so if I've done something wrong, please let me know and I'll do better next time!)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. [Can you simply scale up animals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/316/can-you-simply-scale-up-animals) might be helpful for you. The accepted answer briefly talks about aquatic animals and the general problems. Have fun on the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the things determining the size for swimming creatures are *breathing*, and *feeding*. As long as you manage to get oxygen and nutrients to every bodypart, they can end up in sizes that we would consider islands.